# How does Rayon prevent the use of RefCell<T>, Cell<T> and Rc<T> between threads?

Tags: rust, thread-safety, rayon, interior-mutability

The Rayon documentation say it guarantees that using Rayon APIs will not introduce data races.

How can the compiler know that the method called by the closures is not sharing mutable state, for example `RefCell<T>` and `Cell<T>`, or using structs that are not thread-safe, for example `Rc<T>`?

I understand that `core::marker::Sync` marks types that are safe to share between threads but I don't understand how the Rayon type declarations and the compiler enforce it!

Comment: Literally in the beginning of README "You may also enjoy [this blog post](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2015/12/18/rayon-data-parallelism-in-rust/) about Rayon, which gives more background and details about how it works"

Comment: All I could find is that it use Join which define the closure type as “FnOnce() -> R_A + Send” but this does not explain why this type closure would not use any RefCell<t> internally!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually answered your question yourself – all closures that need to be shared between threads need to be `Sync`, and Rayon's API simply requires them to be `Sync` via trait bounds. See for example the [documentation of `ParallelIterator::map()`](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.0.3/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html#method.map), which specifies the method as

```
fn map<F, R>(self, map_op: F) -> Map<Self, F> where
    F: Fn(Self::Item) -> R + Sync + Send,
    R: Send,
```

There isn't any deeper magic here – whenever Rayon uses a closure in a way that requires it to be `Sync`, e.g. by passing it on to a lower level API, Rayon restricts the corresponding parameter type with the `Sync` trait bound. This in turn makes sure  that everything stored inside the closure is `Sync`, so you can't store any `RefCell` in the closure.

In cases like this, you can also ask the compiler for an explanation. As an example, if you try to compile this code

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let c = RefCell::new(5);
    let _ = [1, 2, 3]
        .par_iter()
        .map(|i| i * *c.borrow())
        .sum();
}
```

you will get this error ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=deafacaaf19570feda7c00d4a019e757))

```
error[E0277]: `std::cell::RefCell<i32>` cannot be shared between threads safely
  --> src/main.rs:10:10
   |
10 |         .map(|i| i * *c.borrow())
   |          ^^^ `std::cell::RefCell<i32>` cannot be shared between threads safely
   |
   = help: within `[closure@src/main.rs:10:14: 10:33 c:&std::cell::RefCell<i32>]`, the trait `std::marker::Sync` is not implemented for `std::cell::RefCell<i32>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `&std::cell::RefCell<i32>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[closure@src/main.rs:10:14: 10:33 c:&std::cell::RefCell<i32>]`
```

While the compiler unfortunately does not directly mention the trait bound for the parameter of `map()`, it still points you to the relevant method, and explains that it expects the closure to be `Sync`, and the reason why it isn't.

Comment: Speaking of Sync/Send only, is there any type that is a `Sync` but not a `Send`?

Comment: @soupybionics Of course you can define one, but there are also a few in the standard library, e.g. `MutexGuard`.

Comment: Thanks. Also if a type is `Sync` and `Copy`, there's no reason it can't be `Send`, right?

Comment: @soupybionics I can't see a good use case for a type that is `Sync` and `Copy`, but not `Send`. It seems if you can share a reference and then copy the value, you should also be allowed to send the value directly, but sometimes there are sublteties that aren't immediately obvious, so I wouldn't take this as a proof there can't be such a type.